# Wordpress - Add custom field to database while user sign up

Tags: php, wordpress, hash, authentication

I created another column into `wp_user` table in database and Im trying to store password in a different way of hashing to use as credential for another app

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

where should I add the code to use input field data before it gets hashed?

**Its important to add this command before user get registered because I need to use the raw password from the user input field**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wordpress has an action hook called [`user_register`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) that triggers immidiatly after a user was inserted into db .

Example from [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register)

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
```

and your funciton

```
function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

   if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['first_name']);

}
```

**Edit I**

After comment : First - you can hash or change the password at any point you like with other methods - but i will not get into that so if you need some earlier action you can use [register_form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_form) to manipulate the form itself , or you can use [register_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_post) to manipulate or handle post data from a user registration before the [register_errors](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_errors) filter - which depending on your scenario you could also use.

All of these extra functions are linked in the `user_register` codex page.

**Edit II**

after comment :

> think I should edit register_form, which file exactly?

never NEVER **NEVER** edit core files.

This is about the worse practice that a developer can do for so many reasons that I can not even begin to enumerate here .
This is exactly why hooks / filters were made.

If you already know that , then use them, and if you do not - you can read more  [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference).

The hook `register_form` in this case is exactly for manipulating the form and you can change the form without touching core files.

**Edit III**

Please check also function: [wp_hash_password](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password) and [wp_set_password](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password) that allows to change the default hashing algorithm.

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_hash_password') ){
    function wp_hash_password($password) {
                //your own hashing algorithm here
            return $password;
    } }
```

if you do so you will also need to change [wp_check_password](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password)

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_check_password') ){
    function wp_check_password($password, $hash, $user_id = '') {
            // do you hash checking
            return apply_filters('check_password', $check, $password, $hash, $user_id);
            }
}
```

Comment: Its useless because after inserting user into db I cant retrieve RAW PASSWORD
I need to do it exactly when the user register to hash raw password in a different way

Comment: for example user enter 12345678 as password during registration, it gets hashed like some string in user_pass in database, how can I hash the original password again exactly ?!

Comment: I think I should edit register_form, which file exactly?

Comment: I think the answer is register_form and register_post Thanks

Comment: No problem and happy coding :-) and see `edit III` for more info on your scenario that might be useful for you